AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Gender_Id'. Что здесь можно исправить?

https://disk.yandex.ru/d/8p15G_H359Q4Yw
Ошибка:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Учеба\Учеба\8 семестр\Диплом\PuthonPrograms\main.py", line 206, in on_btnEdit_click
    dialog = UpdateDialog(self.gender, self.status,  init_data)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "e:\Учеба\Учеба\8 семестр\Диплом\PuthonPrograms\main.py", line 146, in __init__
    Gender_Name = gender[init_data.Gender_Id].Name
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Gender_Id'

Код с 19 по 102:
class ItemsModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.items = []
        self.gender = {}
        self.status = {}

    def setItems(self, items):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self.items = items
        self.endResetModel()
        
    
    def setGender(self, gender):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self.gender = gender
        self.endResetModel()

    def setStatus(self, status):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self.status = status
        self.endResetModel()


    def rowCount(self, *args, **kwargs) -> int:
        return len(self.items)
        
    
    def columnCount(self, *args, **kwargs) -> int:
        return 11
    
    def data(self, index: QtCore.QModelIndex, role: QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return
        
        if role == QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            General_information_info = self.items[index.row()] 
            col = index.column()
            if col == 0:
                return f'{General_information_info.NumRoom}'
            elif col == 1:
                Status_title = self.status[General_information_info.Status_Id].Name
                return Status_title
            elif col == 2:
                return f'{General_information_info.Surname}'
            elif col == 3:
                return f'{General_information_info.Name}'
            elif col == 4:
                return f'{General_information_info.MidName}'
            elif col == 5:
                return f'{General_information_info.PhoneNum}'
            elif col == 6:
                return f'{General_information_info.Date}'
            elif col == 7:
                return f'{General_information_info.SumPay}'
            elif col == 8:
                return f'{General_information_info.Introduced}'
            elif col == 9:
                return f'{General_information_info.Remains}'
            elif col == 10:
                Gender_title = self.gender[General_information_info.Gender_Id].Name
                return Gender_title
            elif role == QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.UserRole:
                return self.items[index.row()]

        
    def headerData(self, section: int, orientation: QtCore.Qt.Orientation, role: QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole):
        "NumRoom, Status_Id, Surname, Name, MidName, PhoneNum, Date, SumPay, Introduced, Remains, Gender_Id"
        if role == QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Orientation.Horizontal:
                return {
                    0: "Комната",
                    1: "Статус оплаты",
                    2: "Фамилия",
                    3: "Имя",
                    4: "Отчество",
                    5: "Телефон",
                    6: "Дата рождения",
                    7: "Сумма",
                    8: "Внесено",
                    9: "Отстаток",
                    10: "Пол",
                    
                }.get(section)

Код 146-147:
        Gender_Name = gender[init_data.Gender_Id].Name
        self.ui.cmbGender.setCurrentText(Gender_Name)

Код 202-209
def on_btnEdit_click(self):
        item = self.ui.tblItems.currentIndex()
        init_data = item.data(QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.UserRole)

        dialog = UpdateDialog(self.gender, self.status,  init_data)
        r = dialog.exec()
        if r == 0:
            return


Александр , пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать.

Скинул ссылку на Диск и картинку прикрепил

Александр , мне недоступна ваша ссылка. Полистайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A217323+QAbstractTableModel может что-то полезное найдете.

https://disk.yandex.ru/d/2yxetWn0eI7CBA

Александр , мне недоступна ваша ссылка.  Я вижу только на GitHub
